# How to add Koin to Ktor project

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

I am trying to install "Koin" for DI. I have added the Koin dependency to my gradle but it doesn't seem to install.

```
implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.2")

implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-ktor:3.2")
```

This is my plugin method

```
fun Application.configureDependencyInjection(){
    install(Koin) {
       /*
         My modules are meant to go in here.
       */
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting this error: "Unresolved reference: Koin"

Comment: Did you add the import statement for the class `Koin`?

Comment: I have tried "import org.koin..." and it still cannot resolve koin

Comment: Can you post your complete file? With https://insert-koin.io/docs/quickstart/ktor it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by invalidating cache. I suppose it was a cache issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
// Koin for Kotlin apps
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.2.0"
    // Testing
    testCompileOnly("io.insert-koin:koin-test:3.2.0")
```

it works for me.

Comment: This is not working for Ktor